# Why is the following true? (Conditional expectation)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, martingales

In the book I'm reading, it says, :

> consider a gambler who plays a sequence of fair games. Let X<sub>i</sub> be the amount the gambler wins on the ith game (X<sub>i</sub> is negative if the gambler loses), and let Z<sub>i</sub> be the gambler’s total winnings at the end of the ith game. Because each game is fair, E[X<sub>i</sub>] = 0 *and* E[ Z<sub>i+1</sub> |X<sub>1</sub>,X<sub>2</sub>,...,X<sub>i</sub>]=Z<sub>i</sub> +E[X<sub>i+1</sub>]= Z<sub>i</sub>.

Since game is fair,  **E[X<sub>i</sub>] = 0** is clear to me.

Intuitively, **E[ Z<sub>i+1</sub> |X<sub>1</sub>,X<sub>2</sub>,...,X<sub>i</sub>]=Z<sub>i</sub> +E[X<sub>i+1</sub>]= Z<sub>i</sub>** makes sense as winnings after ***i+1***th game is simply the sum of earnings till ***i***th game, plus expected earning in ***i+1***th round. But how do I formally prove this? Note that this proves Z<sub>i</sub> is a martingale.

Comment: Can you formulate an expression for $Z_{i}$ in terms of the $X's$?

Comment: Yes, Zi = x1+x2+...xi

Comment: Great. Now the rest will follow by basic properties of conditional expectation, are you aware of any basic properties?

Comment: Yes, E(Y|Z=z) = sum over (y*Pr(Y=y|Z=z)) by def.

Comment: By basic I mean stuff like $E[X\mid Y] = E[X]$ if $X$ is independent of $Y$

Comment: Yes, that I know.

Comment: I will give you the outline and if you are unsure I'll write somewhat more detailed in an answer. Write $Z_{i+1} = X_{i+1} + Z_{i}$, use linearity of conditional expectation, note $Z_{i}$ is $X_{1}, \dots, X_{i}$ measurable  and $X_{i+1}$ independent of $X_{1}, \dots, X_{i}$. From here some basic properties will give the answer

Comment: I can see that conditioning and then applying expectation operator on both sides of +1=+1+, will give result, but why are we able to write +1=+1+ in the first place?

Comment: By definition, $$Z_{i+1} = X_{i+1} + X_{i} + \dots + X_{1} = X_{i+1} + (X_{i} + \dots + X_{1})  =X_{i+1}  +Z_{i}$$

Comment: Aah! Right, Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, why does linearity of conditional expectation hold?

Comment: See [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/),
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not 
independent of each other.